# Get text from custom tag

Tags: jquery

How can I get the address from this code with jQuery ?

```
<span property="v:street-address">2 Macdonald street</span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Getting the text or selecting the element? Both things have already been asked.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("span[property='v:street-address']").text()
```